# Keplerian Orbit Estimator

Tags: computational-physics

While calculating the eccentric anomaly of a satellite using the [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), what initial estimate of the root for E (eccentric anomaly) should be taken for least number of iterations(best approximation of root) to take place and why?

Comment: You should probably post some additional details (what is the equation for the root finding problem?), but the answer is almost certainly "The best estimate you have." Assuming "estimate" means "initial guess" to Newton-Raphson, this is highly problem dependent.

Comment: It is also dependent on what the correct value of $E$ is. If you try to estimate a circular orbit, start with $E=0$ for best efficiency. If you have a highly eccentric but elliptic orbit, start with something close to 1 for best efficiency. There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.